# Searching and printing a regular expression in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I need to search an input file which has the regular expression multiple times. I need to print the expression on a new line.

```
"1-BBMD-DC-FB"|4|{47|"Interval"|00:00:00|00:00:00|1}{48|"Interval"|00:00:00|00:00:00|1}{49|"Interval"|00:00:00|00:00:00|1}{52|"Interval"|00:00:00|00:00:00|1}|{1|"Interval"|"All"|0}|{52|"Interval"|"day"}
```

The desired output should be :

```
1-BBMD-DC-FB"|{47|"Interval"|00:00:00|00:00:00|1}
1-BBMD-DC-FB"|{48|"Interval"|00:00:00|00:00:00|1}
....
```

How to achieve this? This is what I tried:

```
while (<IN>) {
    my ($a,$s,$d,$f,$g,$h,$j) = split (/{/, $_);
    #print ("$a \n");
    print ("$a$s \n");
    print ("$a$d \n");
    print ("$a$d \n");
    print ("$a$f \n");
    print ("$a$g \n");
    print ("$a$h \n");
}
close IN;
```

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, show us specifically what you did so we can help you along. **You start it, and then we help. We don't write it for you.** Show us the actual code that you've tried, and then describe what happened and what's not right, and then we can help you from there. Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Comment: @AndyLester

I used the split command, however the input varies.

while (<IN>)
{
my ($a,$s,$d,$f,$g,$h,$j) = split (/{/, $_);
#print ("$a \n");
print ("$a$s \n");
print ("$a$d \n");
print ("$a$d \n");
print ("$a$f \n");
print ("$a$g \n");
print ("$a$h \n");

}
close IN;

Comment: Note that you can do `my ($prefix, @rest) = ...;`

Comment: Can you please confirm if it is correct that the `|4` in `1-BBMD-DC-FB"|4|` should be deleted?

Answer (score 0):

A crude parser (since it parses some parts twice), but simple parser:

```
my $field_re = qr/ "[^"]*" | [^{|}]* /x;
my $curlies_re = qr/ \{ (?: $field_re (?: \| $field_re )* )? \} /x;

while (<>) {
   my ($id, $curlies) = / ^ ( $field_re ) \| $field_re \| ( $curlies_re* ) \| /x
      or die("Invalid input or bad parser\n");

   my @curlies = $curlies =~ /$curlies_re/g;

   print("$id|$_\n") for @curlies;
}
```

Output:

```
"1-BBMD-DC-FB"|{47|"Interval"|00:00:00|00:00:00|1}
"1-BBMD-DC-FB"|{48|"Interval"|00:00:00|00:00:00|1}
"1-BBMD-DC-FB"|{49|"Interval"|00:00:00|00:00:00|1}
"1-BBMD-DC-FB"|{52|"Interval"|00:00:00|00:00:00|1}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/perl/index.html

Will let you test various regex expressions on your data then you can tranlate them to code.

I used {*} as the regex
According to planet regex

```
    $var = $input =~ $regex
$var=1
$`="1-BBMD-DC-FB"|4|{47|"Interval"|00:00:00|00:00:00|1
$&=}
$'={48|"Interval"|00:00:00|00:00:00|1}{49|"Interval"|00:00:00|00:00:00|1}{52|"Interval"|00:00:00|00:00:00|1}|{1|"Interval"|"All"|0}|{52|"Interval"|"day"}
```

Its a good place to experiment

Answer (score 0):

From looking at your input, there is an optional `|` charcacter.

**To print what you want,** replace `}\|?` with `}\n`

`$subject =~ s/}/}\n/g;`

Output:

```
1-BBMD-DC-FB"|4|{47|"Interval"|00:00:00|00:00:00|1}
{48|"Interval"|00:00:00|00:00:00|1}
{49|"Interval"|00:00:00|00:00:00|1}
{52|"Interval"|00:00:00|00:00:00|1}
{1|"Interval"|"All"|0}
{52|"Interval"|"day"}
```

**To split:**

```
@result = split(m/}\|?/, $subject, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my $test = '"1-BBMD-DC-FB"|4|{47|"Interval"|00:00:00|00:00:00|1}{48|"Interval"|00:00:00|00:00:00|1}{49|"Interval"|00:00:00|00:00:00|1}{52|"Interval"|00:00:00|00:00:00|1}|{1|"Interval"|"All"|0}|{52|"Interval"|"day"}';

my ($prefix, @list) = split(/{/, $test);  # split with "{" as delimiter
$prefix =~ s/4\|//g;          # Remove "4|" after the prefix

foreach my $item (@list) {
    $item =~ s/\|$//g;        # Remove "|" that some entires have between "}{"
    print "$prefix{$item\n";  # Put "{" back before each element
}
```

Output:

```
"1-BBMD-DC-FB"| {47|"Interval"|00:00:00|00:00:00|1}
"1-BBMD-DC-FB"| {48|"Interval"|00:00:00|00:00:00|1}
"1-BBMD-DC-FB"| {49|"Interval"|00:00:00|00:00:00|1}
"1-BBMD-DC-FB"| {52|"Interval"|00:00:00|00:00:00|1}
"1-BBMD-DC-FB"| {1|"Interval"|"All"|0}
"1-BBMD-DC-FB"| {52|"Interval"|"day"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using good ole [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html)

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;

    # Split on | not followed by }
    my ($name, $num, $groups, $all, $day) = split /\|(?![^\{\}]*\})/;

    # Separate groups in third field.
    for my $group (split /(?=\{)/, $groups) {
        print "$name|$group\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
"1-BBMD-DC-FB"|4|{47|"Interval"|00:00:00|00:00:00|1}{48|"Interval"|00:00:00|00:00:00|1}{49|"Interval"|00:00:00|00:00:00|1}{52|"Interval"|00:00:00|00:00:00|1}|{1|"Interval"|"All"|0}|{52|"Interval"|"day"}
```

Outputs:

```
"1-BBMD-DC-FB"|{47|"Interval"|00:00:00|00:00:00|1}
"1-BBMD-DC-FB"|{48|"Interval"|00:00:00|00:00:00|1}
"1-BBMD-DC-FB"|{49|"Interval"|00:00:00|00:00:00|1}
"1-BBMD-DC-FB"|{52|"Interval"|00:00:00|00:00:00|1}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$stringName = qq{"1-BBMD-DC-FB"|4|{47|"Interval"|00:00:00|00:00:00|1}{48|"Interval"|00:00:00|00:00:00|1}{49|"Interval"|00:00:00|00:00:00|1}{52|"Interval"|00:00:00|00:00:00|1}|{1|"Interval"|"All"|0}|{52|"Interval"|"day"} };
$stringName =~ s|\}\{|\}\n\{|g;
```

This will split them onto new lines for you with a \n char where you want them.  Optionally you can then split into an array on \n if you need.